# ssh not showing full output of command

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I have a list of servers 20+ that I would like to get the shell that they are using. While logged onto a server I can run the following command

```
$ ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
12022 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
```

Instead of touching each server and doing this I tried to loop it with a list

```
$ for i in `cat servlist`; do echo $i ; ssh $i ps -p $$ ; done
serv1
PID TTY          TIME CMD
serv2
PID TTY          TIME CMD
serv3
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

Looping this does not show the expected output. I then tried to ssh to a single server and run the command but got the same error.

```
$ ssh serv4 ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

Why is this happening, nothing jumps out at me in the ssh man pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the process does not exist.

The `$$` is being evaluated locally, and all servers are being passed the same number. A number that is not a currently used PID on the servers.

All the `$` stuff is done by the shell, not the commands. You need to escape it, so that it is evaluated by the shell on the server.

Try `\$\$`

---

e.g.

```
for i in $(cat servlist); do echo $i; ssh $i 'ps -p $$'; done
```

untested

Comment: I did not think to look more into the ps -p $$ command.

When running 
`for i in 'cat servlist'; do echo $i ; ssh $i ps -p \$\$
 serv1
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
7199 ?        00:00:00 ps
serv2
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13842 ?        00:00:00 ps`

It did just occur to me to cat /etc/passwd | grep user" and find the default shell that way.

Comment: @JonWright `getent passwd | awk -F: '$1=="user" {print $7}'` will show you the login shell for "user". Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @roaima yes this is what I wanted. From habit I wanted to use ps -p $$.

Comment: Top tip. use `$(command)` instead of (I can not type this) using back ticks.